# Excel add in using office js - How to add html string to Excel text box

Tags: excel, office-js

Hello all I have created a excel add in using "Office js" in that allows the user to select cell ranges based on which a NLG narration is returned from my backend. The response from my backend is a html string, I would like to render this html inside excel text box. Can anyone help me out. Please do not suggest me to write a regex to strip down HTML tags because it removes all text formates and styles along with it.

I have used addTextBox function of office js to create a text box which accepts string as a parameter.

```
const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
  const shapes = sheet.shapes;
  const textbox = shapes.addTextBox(richText);
```

I am also interested in alternatives like format conversions or any other logics

In case of any other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks naveen, can you do this in UI? if you can, this should be a new feature ask, and then you could submit your request in uservoice and upvote for this feature at https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback?category_id=163563. and upvote for this feature. thanks for your support

Comment: Thanks @Raymound Lu hope requesting for a new feature is the only solution.

Comment: Thanks naveen, can you please share a bit more about your scenario, we would like to understand more about your use case

Answer (score 0):

The textbox is not an HTML viewer so it cannot render HTML.

Comment: Thanks rick. I am aware that it is not a html render. Is there any work around to persist the text format's like the one imposed by h1 tags inside the text box

Comment: Your original question said " I would like to render this html inside excel text box". It now appears that you want to convert the HTML to another format and render the other format. Please rewrite your question to make clear what you are actually asking for.